# fuser process php5 cron job using high amounts of cpu

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, cron, cpu

We are seeing our server's CPU spike at 30 minute intervals. this is likely caused by php5 job to cleanup session files. this is taken from our /etc/cron.d/php5 on the server:

```
# /etc/cron.d/php5: crontab fragment for php5
#  This purges session files older than X, where X is defined in seconds
#  as the largest value of session.gc_maxlifetime from all your php.ini
#  files, or 24 minutes if not defined.  See /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime

# Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -ignore_readdir_race -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
```

there seems to have been a problem with this job in past releases. there was a problem in version 11.10 of Ubuntu with this taking high amounts of CPU but we are running much later builds of both Ubuntu and PHP.
how important is this job for PHP? can we stop this job from running or lower its priority?

Comment: Just because the CPU is spiking doesn't mean there's necessarily any cause for concern. The files will have to be cleaned up at some point, at which they may as well be cleaned up as quickly as possible, using as many resources as are available to get the job done. Are you saying this job is taxing the server *unreasonably*?

Comment: it may be using the resources well but the problem is that this job will take 2 minutes or so to complete, and that extra cpu usage at rush hours can stop us from responding to requests during that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeatedly and recursively scratching the filesystem for garbage with find and fuser is generally a bad idea.

Move away from storing sessions in files and you instantly get rid of this and a lot of other problems, if not already done. If you are actually not using file storage for sessions, just delete that line (or comment out).

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug, it appears to be realted to the pmisc package but is also part of the php5 when php5-apc is functional.
There is an ubuntu bug report and suggested workaroud mentioned here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/876387

```
09,39 * * * * root [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -delete
```

and a Debian bug report here:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=633100

I have tested the workaround on debian wheezy and it works, although updating the package would be better!